# Using multiple sections VS a single section with entry types

Tags: sections, entry-type, performance

I'm just planning ahead for a project and was hoping for a second opinion.

I'm going to be making a site that will have about 7 different types of entry - all of which have different fields/URL's; *however* **on the front-end they will all behave as if they are part of one channel**. I will have a single page that lists all of the entries and I will also be giving end-users the ability to perform searches/filtering.

For the sake of easy dashboard management I have currently set them up as **separate sections** instead of **one section with multiple entry types** (because using individual sections gives me a nice separated 'Entries' page in the dashboard - it's hard to sort/view by entry type at the moment).

**Question:** Seeing as I can get the site to work the same regardless of which method I use, is there a dramatic difference between pulling out entries from multiple sections VS pulling out entries from one?

*For this example lets just say we are dealing with around 100,000 entries total.*

Comment: How about setting up both options on a test install and see how it feels by adding some content to each approach.

Comment: @KSPR Good advice - Matt has made a good point about relational data below - which rules out the user of entry types. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to answer without examples of your content types.

I would suggest that if you would ever need deliberately **relate** one Entry to another using the **Entries field type**, then making use of separate Sections for each type of content would be the way to go.

e.g. If an "office location" entry is the parent to multiple "services"

A more obvious factor is when an entry type needs to be a Channel vs a Structure. This can only be set at the Section-level

Hope that helps

Comment: Great point  - competely forgot that you can't limit entry selection by entry type when using an 'entries' field (at this point in time). Seeing as I will be needing to relate entries to other SPECIFIC types of entry then that answers my question. Cheers Matt.

Comment: Awesome, glad to help!